# Смайлы

Tags: нормы-языка

Смайлы, насколько мне известно, придумал Набоков. Сейчас без них сложно представить интернет-общение. Да и мне не раз приходилось попадать впросак из-за отсутствия смайликов — просто не было понятно, что человек имел в виду.
Как вы думаете, станут ли со временем смайлики узаконенным знаком препинания?

Comment: Не раз приходило ощущение замешательства от смайликов — просто не было понятно, что человек имел в виду и почему не проще пользоваться словом, звуком.

Answer (score 1):

Про Набокова:

**Владимир Набоков.** Я часто думаю, что должен существовать специальный типографский знак, обозначающий улыбку, — нечто вроде выгнутой линии, лежащей навзничь скобки,, именно этот значок я поставил бы вместо ответа на ваш вопрос.
*Интервью в апреле 1969 года (перевод А. Г. Николаевской). Опубликовано в сборнике Nabokov V. Strong Opinions.*

http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/135/

Насколько это правда — не знаю.

Comment: Это возможно, но можно ли такой знак называть смайлом? Ведь он *типографский*.

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не слышал про Набокова. Да и зачем ему смайлы? На машинке печатать?
Смайлы появились одновременно с компьютерной связью (прообразами современной электронной почты и интернета).
Думаю, что они никогда не станут "знаками препинания", у них очень ограниченное поле применимости.

Comment: Марк Из, спасибо.